# each() within each() and addClass within hasClass somehow doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Yet another head scratcher, this one! Why does everything in the below work, except for the ONE addClass() line?

```
var arr = ['1000','1001','1002','1003','1004','1005'],
    allarr = 0;

$.each(arr, function(i, value) {
   $('#parent ul.list1 li a, #parent ul.list2 li a').each(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('n-'+value)) {
         console.log('yes for: '+$(this).html()); //WORKS: it lists 6x "Something"
         allarr++; //WORKS: in the end, it says "6"
         $(this).addClass('active'); //DOES NOT WORK.

      } else {
         $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
   });
});
console.log('allarr: '+allarr);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list1">
   <li><a class="n-1000">Something</a></li>
   <li><a class="n-1001">Something</a></li>
   <li><a class="n-1003">Something</a></li>
   <li><a class="n-1005">Something</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
   <li><a class="n-1002">Something</a></li>
   <li><a class="n-1004">Something</a></li>
   <li><a class="n-1006 active">Something that should have the active class REMOVED</a></li>
</ul>
```

Weird, no? And help would be appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I just replaced `$(this).addClass('active');` with `$(this).addClass('active areyoukidding');` - and guess what, that second class gets added without a problem. `active` still just gets ignored. Has anyone come across this previously? There is no other place in the app where this could get overridden later; and I'm already adding `active` classes in many other places in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping through every element six times...

- For element `1000`, add `active`, remove `active` from everything else.
- For element `1001`, add `active`, remove `active` from everything else (undoes above)
- ...

since element `1005` is the last one that runs that logic, only it will be left with `active`

Comment: Well, you are absolutely correct. Of course. I moved the else clause before the first loop and it works perfectly now. Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes :) Thanks!